# Swift dictionary set value of a key by value of another key with format: "value_of_key1=value_of_key2"

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm working with Dictionary on Swift 4 which have this format in a delegate before send it to another view controller:

```
{
"search_key": "color"
"option_value": "409"
}
```

My requirement is send it to server with format like this: `color=409` because it will use as a param in request URL. I tried to make it like this code below but it's display as `search_key=409`

```
data["search_key"] = itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key.count > 0 ?  itemFilter[indexPath.section].search_key : strData.search_key;
data["option_value"] = strData.option_value
dataAfterSet["search_key"] = strData.option_value //this line is when I try to set the format and it show `search_key=409`

guard let dataNew = data as? [NSObject : Any] else {return}

delegate.filterTableCellDidSelectItem(item: dataNew, indexPath: indexPath)
```

So, how can I combine them? And can I make it but still keep type Dictionary because in delegate I pass it to other in dictionary??

Comment: you want to add it to URL or send it in Body?

Comment: I add it to URL as a param, but because my request function receiver only Dictionary so I need pass it to ViewController and keep it same type

Comment: try running it in postman once and show us how you are sending data. then we can help.

Comment: Solved it. I'm calling it in wrong place, I'm process in delegate calling in ViewController and it's worked. Anyway, thank you for attend to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass it in body, i think you need this:

```
[
"search_key": [
 "color" : 405
],
"option_value": "409"
]
```

If you are trying to pass it in URL :

```
let valueToPass = "color=\(405)" // replace 405 with your int value 
let YOUR_URL = "https://example.com/api/" // dont forget the backslash
let url = YOUR_URL + valueToPass
```